# CSS and styling , Ruby on Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have implemented a Rails project which has a lot of forms, but they do not look good. The `new`, `edit`, and `destroy` buttons are very close to each other. Listing the items in each form is also ugly as the columns are very close; they definitely need CSS and styling. Is there any sample or template that I can use?

Comment: 1. show us what you got. 2. Take a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For general styling** you can use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), there is even a [gem](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails) to make it easier to integrate.

**For better layouts and automating the form building** process such as new, edit actions, you can use [Formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic).

Another one that's as popular is [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form).

You can find even more form builders at the [ruby toolbox site](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_form_builders).

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned little about your application, its hard to tell what styling you should chose. However as @olive_tree mentioned, bootstrap is simpler and a convenient option. You may want to check this rails cast

http://railscasts.com/episodes/328-twitter-bootstrap-basics?view=asciicast

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is definitely a good place to start. Personally I prefer ZURB Foundation, though, but that is mostly a matter of preference. Here is a link on how to integrate Foundation the easiest way:

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/applications.html